# How to stop executing next function with async-await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2016

I'm using this library to chain asynchronous functions in my nodejs app:
https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait

```
var chain = async(function(){

    var foo = await(bar());
    var foo2 = await(bar2());
    var foo3 = await(bar2());

}
```

So bar3 waits for bar2 to finish and bar2 waits for bar() to finish. That's fine. But what will I do in order to stop the async block from further execution? I mean something like this:

```
var chain = async(function(){

    var foo = await(bar());
    if(!foo){return false;} // if bar returned false, quit the async block
    var foo2 = await(bar2());
    var foo3 = await(bar2());

}
```

what's the best approach to handle this?

at the moment I throw an exception within bar and handle the exception in way:

```
chain().catch(function (err) { //handler, ie log message)
```

It's working, but it doesn't look right

Comment: Doesn't `return false` as you wrote it just work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I mean something like this …

asyncawait supports *exactly* this syntax. Just `return` from the function:

```
var chain = async(function(){
    var foo = await(bar());
    if (!foo) return;
    var foo2 = await(bar2());
    var foo3 = await(bar2());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, and depending on your usage, you may want your `bar()`s to `throw`/reject.

```
async function bar() {
  try {
    Api.fetch(...) // `fetch` is a Promise
  } catch (err) {
    // custom error handling
    throw new Error() // so that the caller will break out of its `try`

    // or re-throw the error that you caught, for the caller to use
    throw err
  }

  // or, instead of a try/catch here, you can just return the Promise
  return Api.fetch(...)
}

var chain = async(function(){
  try {
    // if any of these throw or reject, we'll exit the `try` block
    var foo = await(bar());
    var foo2 = await(bar2());
    var foo3 = await(bar2());
  } catch {} // ES2019 optional catch. may need to configure eslint to be happy
});
```