# When using async/await, how do you stop execution of a function when one call errors out?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Lets imagine we have a function as so:

```
Router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  let result = await someFunction().catch(next)
  someOtherCall()
})
```

If this errors out, it continues on to the global error handler by calling `next(error_reason)`.  However, if the `someFunction()` fails, we don't want `someOtherCall()` to run at all.  At the moment, I can see two ways of fixing this:

```
// Suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/q/28835780/3832377
Router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  let result = await someFunction().catch(next)
  if (!result) return // Ugly, especially if we have to run it after every call.
  someOtherCall()
})

Router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  let result = someFunction().then(() => {
    // Much less work, but gets us back to using callbacks, which async/await were
    // meant to help fix for us.
    someOtherCall()
  }).catch(next)
})
```

Is there a simpler way to stop a function from executing if any of the functions call that doesn't mean adding another statement after every function call or using callbacks?

Comment: Why not using promises to accomplish this

Comment: @Volem We are using promises, someFunction() returns a promise that resolves when the function runs successfully or throws when the function errors out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `try-catch`:

```
Router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  try { 
    let result = await someFunction()
    someOtherCall()
  }
  catch(exception) {
    next(exception)
  }
})
```